# Where is the line between unit testing application logic and distrusting language constructs?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd

Consider a function like this:

```
function savePeople(dataStore, people) {
    people.forEach(person => dataStore.savePerson(person));
}
```

It might be used like this:

```
myDataStore = new Store('some connection string', 'password');
myPeople = ['Joe', 'Maggie', 'John'];
savePeople(myDataStore, myPeople);
```

Let us *assume* that `Store` has its own unit tests, or is vendor-provided.  In any case, we trust `Store`.  And let us further assume that error handling -- eg, of database disconnection errors -- is not the responsibility of `savePeople`.  Indeed, let us assume that the *store itself* is magical database that cannot possibly error in any way.  *Given* these assumptions, the question is:

**Should `savePeople()` be unit tested, or would such tests amount to testing the built-in `forEach` language construct?**

We could, of course, pass in a mock `dataStore` and assert that `dataStore.savePerson()` is called once for each person.  You could certainly make the argument that such a test provides security against implementation changes: eg, if we decided to replace `forEach` with a traditional `for` loop, or some other method of iteration.  So the test is not *entirely* trivial.  And yet it seems awfully close...

---

Here's another example that may be more fruitful.  Consider a function that does nothing but coordinate other objects or functions.  For example:

```
function bakeCookies(dough, pan, oven) {
    panWithRawCookies = pan.add(dough);
    oven.addPan(panWithRawCookies);
    oven.bakeCookies();
    oven.removePan();
}
```

How should a function like this be unit tested, assuming you think it should?  It's hard for me to imagine any kind of unit test that doesn't simply mock `dough`, `pan`, and `oven`, and then assert that methods are called on them.  But such a test is doing nothing more than duplicating the exact implementation of the function.

Does this inability to test the function in a meaningful black box way indicate a design flaw with the function itself?  If so, how could it be improved?

---

To give even more clarity to the question motivating the `bakeCookies` example, I'll add a more realistic scenario, which is one I've encountered when attempting to add tests to and refactor legacy code.

When a user creates a new account, a number of things need to happen: 1) a new user record needs to be created in the database  2) a welcome email needs to be sent 3) the user's IP address needs to be recorded for fraud purposes.

So we want to create a method that ties together all the "new user" steps:

```
function createNewUser(validatedUserData, emailService, dataStore) {
  userId = dataStore.insertUserRecord(validateduserData);
  emailService.sendWelcomeEmail(validatedUserData);
  dataStore.recordIpAddress(userId, validatedUserData.ip);
}
```

Note that if any of these methods throws an error, we want the error to bubble up to the calling code, so that it can handle the error as it sees fit.  If it's being called by the API code, it may translate the error into an appropriate http response code.  If it's being called by a web interface, it may translate the error into an appropriate message to be displayed to the user, and so on.  The point is *this function* doesn't know how to handle the errors that may be thrown.

The essence of my confusion is that to unit test such a function it seems necessary to repeat the exact implementation in the test itself (by specifying that methods are called on mocks in a certain order) and that seems wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should we test all our methods?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/130925/should-we-test-all-our-methods)

Comment: see also: [What kind of code would Kent Beck avoid unit testing?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/244709/31260)

Comment: After it runs. Do you have cookies

Comment: Worth a read, though focused on Apple's Cocoa development: [Trust but verify](https://eschatologist.net/blog/?p=16)

Comment: regarding your update: why would you ever want to mock a pan? or dough? these sound like simple in-memory objects that should be trivial to create, and so there's no reason why you shouldn't test them as one unit. remember, the "unit" in "unit testing" doesn't mean "a single class". it means "the smallest possible unit of code that is used to get something done". a pan is probably nothing more than a container for dough objects, so it'd be contrived to test it in isolation instead of just test-driving the bakeCookies method from the outside in.

Comment: On the first example, if you don't want to spend time on building a unit test, you can safely replace it by a source code inspection.

Comment: @mouviciel source code inspections take longer time, involve more people and don't protect against regressions. sounds like a down-grade to me?

Comment: @kai: It depends on how it is actually performed: looking at that part of code to verify that `forEach` is used and reporting it on whatever document is required for test results shouldn't take much time. It can even be automated with some `grep`/`awk`/`python` hack.

Comment: At the end of the day, the fundamental principle at work here is that you write enough tests to assure yourself that the code works, and that it's an adequate "canary in the coal mine" when someone changes something.  That's it.  There are no magical incantations, formulaic suppositions or dogmatic assertions, which is why 85% to 90% code coverage (not 100%) is widely considered *excellent.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey hits the nail on the head. There is not a general case for Unit Testing. You should test in a responsible way - that doesn't mean testing every single possible line of code, but testing _enough_ lines of codes to know that your software works.

Comment: @RobertHarvey unfortunately formulaic platitudes and TDD sound bites, while sure to earn you enthusiastic nods of agreement, don't help solve real-world problems.  for that you need to get your hands dirty and risk answering an actual question

Comment: In this case, a test for savePeople is not really testing if that lambda works - it would be testing if the lambda was there and calling the correct method in the first place.

Comment: can I have cookies too?

Comment: It depends on what you are are writing.  If you are building a space shuttle or cryptographic code, yes, you should be testing even language constructs - with code not written in that language.  If you are writing a tweetbot I hope that you write no tests whatsoever and that it dies horribly, no offence intended.  How long IS your piece of string?

Comment: Unit test in order of decreasing cyclomatic complexity. Trust me, you'll run out of time before you get to this function

Comment: For your last example (adding a user) it appears that those method calls need to be called in that specific order to be successful.  Since you would need to successfully save the user to the database to get back the userId to then use to save the IP address.  Welcome email could potentially have an execution order dependency as well if it contains a link for the user to verify their email address with the application.  So my unit test would mock out dataStore and emailService and then assert on the order that the methods were called and the data they were called with ...

Comment: This is why I generally fall on the side of trying to unit test all accessible logic.  Sometimes it is easy to miss things in seemingly trivial code.  Also in your "oven" example you could potentially be declaring panWithRawCookies in the global scope if that is clientside code.  I have found it useful to use a method that asserts that nothing has been leaked to the global the scope when I write my clientside javascript unit tests.

Answer (score 122):

*Should `savePeople()` be unit tested?* Yes. You aren't testing that `dataStore.savePerson` works, or that the db connection works, or even that the `foreach` works. You are testing that `savePeople` fulfills the promise it makes through its contract.

Imagine this scenario: someone does a big refactor of the code base, and accidentally removes the `forEach` part of the implementation so that it always only saves the first item. Wouldn't you want a unit test to catch that?

Comment: `... you aren't testing that the functions it calls work, you're testing that it calls the correct functions.` -- Technically, that would make it an *integration* test, wouldn't it?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: There's a lot of gray area, and making the distinction, IMO, isn't important. You are right though -- it's not really important to test that "it calls the right functions" but rather "it does the right thing" regardless of how it does it. What is important is to test that, given a specific set of inputs to the function you get a specific set of outputs. However, I can see how that last sentence can be confusing, so I removed it.

Comment: _"You are testing that savePeople fulfills the promise it makes through its contract."_ This. So much this.

Comment: Unless you have a "end to end" system test that covers it.

Comment: @Ian End to end tests do not replace unit tests, they are complimentary. Just because you may have an end to end test that ensures you cave save a list of people does not mean you shouldn't have a unit test to also cover it.

Comment: @BryanOakley, so do you recommend the unit test I suggested, ie, asserting that `savePerson` is called with the expected names on a mock?  If not, what unit test do you recommend?   And if you have time, I'd love your input on my update 2 question.  Thanks.

Comment: @VincentSavard, but the cost/benefit of a unit test is reduce if the risk is control in anther way.

Comment: @Jonah: I don't have a recommendation, there's not enough info. Giving concrete answers to abstract questions is difficult. The test is conceptually simple: call it with at least three persons, and verify the data gets saved. How you do that verification is beside the point: you asked _if_ it should be tested, not _how_.

Comment: @BryanOakley Let me know what additional info you need to make the decision.  I'm really interested in *how*, and in what factors influence the types of tests that are appropriate.  Thanks.  EDIT: Also, I'm specifically interested in how to test this as a pure unit test (ie, without using a functional test database, and making assertions on what ends up inside of it)

Comment: @Jonah I'd be interested in that too, but that sounds like another question.

Comment: @Beska Maybe so.  I'll let this post run its course first though....

Comment: I would say it like this: unit test it with a _unit test_ that **won't change** unless the contract for the function changes (in which case you should consider deprecating it and making a new function, anyway). Now the _implementation_ of the function **can change**, you'll catch falsy ones with the unit test.

Comment: @WorldSEnder, yes.  the difficult question is what the unit test should look like.

Comment: @Jonah the details of that is very specific to the function you actually have to test. It should look like it's checking the contract was fulfilled though, whatever the actual contract is, and whatever mocks/components are needed to do that.

Comment: "It's hard for me to imagine any kind of unit test that doesn't simply mock dough, pan, and oven, and then assert that methods are called on them." Then write that test. At minimum, you have a regression test making sure that later changes don't break the code. Beyond that, there's [slebetman's answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/322948/91339). And beyond that, there's refactoring `Oven` into a more OO class that accepts a pan full of cookies and bakes it (rejecting an empty pan).

Comment: You have to wrap your head around this: A unit test should not check if the code does what the developer thinks it should do after reading the code. `A Unit test should check the promised contract` That could be "produces cookies with x,y,z attributes" or "you can query these persons in the database after this method completed" - because maybe just saving them all is not enough and you need to commit, or refresh something, mark cache stale...

Comment: @Falco, It's not clear what the "contract" is (please refer to my *last*  `createNewUser` example in further discussion).  You can argue either 1) `createNewUser` promises to save a user and fraud record, and send an email or 2) that the actual creation of databases records is the the domain of the dataStore, and should be tested there, and similarly for the actual sending of emails, and `createNewUser` just delegates.  If you argue for 1), why decompose your system at all, if you are going to repeat the same tests at every level of abstraction?   That's integration, not unit, testing.

Comment: Since the incoming argument is named __people__, I simply can't imagine the code being "accidently" changed to only save one.  You'd have to make two mistakes, removing the `forEach` and __also__ adding a `[0]`.

Answer (score 38):

Usually this kind of question comes up when people do "test-after" development. Approach this problem from the point of view of TDD, where tests come before the implementation, and ask yourself this question again as an exercise.

At least in my application of TDD, which is usually outside-in, I'd not be implementing a function like `savePeople` after having implemented `savePerson`. The `savePeople` and `savePerson` functions would start as one and being test-driven from the same unit tests; the separation between the two would arise after a few tests, in the refactoring step. This mode of work would also pose the question of where the function `savePeople` ought to be - whether it is a free function or part of the `dataStore`.

In the end, the tests would not only check if you can correctly save a `Person` in the `Store`, but also many persons. This would also lead me to question if other checks are necessary, for instance, "Do I need to make sure that the `savePeople` function is atomic, either saving all or none?", "Can it just somehow return errors for the people that couldn't be saved? How would those errors look like?", and so on. All this amounts to much more than just checking for the use of a `forEach` or other forms of iteration.

Though, if the requirement of saving more than one person at once came only after `savePerson` was already delivered, then I'd update the existing tests of `savePerson` to run through the new function `savePeople`, making sure it still can save one person by simply delegating at first, then test-drive the behavior for more than one person through new tests, thinking if it would be necessary to make the behavior atomic or not.

Comment: Basically test the interface, not the implementation.

Comment: Fair and insightful points.  Yet I feel somehow my *real* question is being dodged :)  Your answer is saying, "In the real world, in a well designed system, I don't think this simplified version of your problem would exist."  Again, fair, but I specifically created this simplified version to highlight the essence of a more general problem.  If you can't get past the artificial nature of the example, you could perhaps imagine another example in which you did have a good reason for a similar function, which did only iteration and delegation.  Or perhaps you think that it is simply impossible?

Comment: @Jonah updated. I hope it answers your question a bit better. This is all very opinion-based and may be against the goal for this site, but it is certainly a very interesting discussion to have. By the way, I tried to answer from the point of view of professional work, where we must strive to leave unit tests for all application behavior, regardless of how trivial the implementation may be, because we have the duty to build a well tested and documented system for new maintainers if we leave. For personal or, say, non-critical (money is also critical) projects, I have a very different opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  How exactly would you test `savePeople`?  As I described in the last paragraph of OP or some other way?

Comment: I'd test the whole behavior, meaning, to check if `savePeople` does indeed save the `Person` objects into the `Store`, no mocks involved. This does not mean the tests would be duplicated for the `savePerson` function - it would be tested **through** the `savePeople` function's tests. This is something Kent Beck talks about in his TDD videos and book, to test the complex part of behavior through the O(1) case, then the small variations for O(n) case, but all through the same function.

Comment: So you would you use a test database of some sort, and do asserts against that, to ensure that the test data actually go inserted as expected?  Wouldn't it become an integration test at that point?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear with the "no mocks involved" part. I meant I wouldn't use a mock for the `savePerson` function like you suggested, instead I'd test it through the more general `savePeople`. The unit tests for `Store` would be changed to run through `savePeople` rather than directly call `savePerson`, so for this, no mocks are used. But the database of course should not be present, as we'd like to isolate coding problems from the various integration problems that occur with actual databases, so here we still have a mock.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41484/discussion-between-jonah-and-michelhenrich).

Answer (score 27):

> Should savePeople() be unit tested

Yes, it should. But try to write your test conditions in a way that is independent from the implementation. For example, turning your usage example into a unit test:

```
function testSavePeople() {
    myDataStore = new Store('some connection string', 'password');
    myPeople = ['Joe', 'Maggie', 'John'];
    savePeople(myDataStore, myPeople);
    assert(myDataStore.containsPerson('Joe'));
    assert(myDataStore.containsPerson('Maggie'));
    assert(myDataStore.containsPerson('John'));
}
```

This test does multiple things:

- it verifies the contract of the function `savePeople()`
- it does not care about the implementation of `savePeople()`
- it documents the example usage of `savePeople()`

Take note that you can still mock/stub/fake the data store. In this case I wouldn't check for explicit function calls, but for the result of the operation. This way my test is prepared for future changes/refactors.

For example, your data store implementation might provide a `saveBulkPerson()` method in the future - now a change to the implementation of `savePeople()` to use `saveBulkPerson()` would not break the unit test as long as `saveBulkPerson()` works as expected. And if `saveBulkPerson()` somehow does not work as expected, your unit test *will* catch that.

> or would such tests amount to testing the built-in forEach language construct?

As said, try to test for expected results and the function interface, not for the implementation (unless you are doing integration tests - then catching specific function calls might be of use). *If there are multiple ways to implement a function, all of them should work with your unit test.*

Regarding your update of the question:

Test for state changes! E.g. some of the dough will be used. According to your implementation, assert that the amount of used `dough` fits into `pan` or assert that the `dough` is used up. Assert that the `pan` contains cookies after the function call. Assert that the `oven` is empty/in the same state as before.

For additional tests, verify edge cases: What happens if the `oven` is not empty before the call? What happens if there isn't enough `dough`? If the `pan` is already full?

You should be able to deduce all the required data for these tests from the dough, pan and oven objects themselves. No need to capture the function calls. Treat the function as if its implementation would not be available to you!

In fact, most TDD users write their tests before they write the function so they are not dependent on the actual implementation.

---

For your latest addition:

> When a user creates a new account, a number of things need to happen: 1) a new user record needs to be created in the database 2) a welcome email needs to be sent 3) the user's IP address needs to be recorded for fraud purposes.
>
> So we want to create a method that ties together all the "new user" steps:
>
> ```
> function createNewUser(validatedUserData, emailService, dataStore) {
>     userId = dataStore.insertUserRecord(validateduserData);
>     emailService.sendWelcomeEmail(validatedUserData);
>     dataStore.recordIpAddress(userId, validatedUserData.ip);
> }
> ```

For a function like this i would mock/stub/fake (whatever seems more general) the `dataStore` and `emailService` parameters. This function does not do any state transitions on any parameter on its own, it delegates them to methods of some of them. I would try to verify that the call to the function did 4 things:

- it inserted a user into the data store
- it sent (or at least called the corresponding method) a welcome email
- it recorded the users IP into the data store
- it delegated any exception/error it encountered (if any)

The first 3 checks can be done with mocks, stubs or fakes of `dataStore` and `emailService` (you really don't want to send emails when testing). Since I had to look this up for some of the comments, these are the differences:

- A fake is an object that behaves the same as the original and is to a certain extent indistinguishable. Its code can normally be reused across tests. This can, for example, be a simple in-memory database for a database wrapper.
- A stub just implements as much as needed to fulfill the required operations of this test. In most cases, a stub is specific to a test or a group of tests requiring only a small set of the methods of the original. In this example, it could be a `dataStore` that just implements a suitable version of `insertUserRecord()` and `recordIpAddress()`.
- A mock is an object that lets you verify how it is used (most often by letting you evaluate calls to its methods). I'd try to use them sparingly in unit tests since by using them you actually try to test the function implementation and not the adherence to its interface, but they still have their uses. Many mock frameworks exists to help you create just the mock you need.

> Note that if any of these methods throws an error, we want the error to bubble up to the calling code, so that it can handle the error as it sees fit. If it's being called by the API code, it may translate the error into an appropriate HTTP response code. If it's being called by a web interface, it may translate the error into an appropriate message to be displayed to the user, and so on. The point is this function doesn't know how to handle the errors that may be thrown.

Expected exceptions/errors are valid test cases: You confirm, that, in case such an event happens, the function behaves the way you expect it would. This can be achieved by letting the corresponding mock/fake/stub object throw when desired.

> The essence of my confusion is that to unit test such a function it seems necessary to repeat the exact implementation in the test itself (by specifying that methods are called on mocks in a certain order) and that seems wrong.

Sometimes this has to be done (though you mostly care about this in integration tests). More often, there are other ways to verify the expected side effects/state changes.

Verifying exact functions calls makes for rather brittle unit tests: Only small changes to the original function causes them to fail. This can be desired or not, but it requires a change to the corresponding unit test(s) whenever you change a function (be it refactoring, optimizing, bug fixing, ...).

Sadly, in that case the unit test loses some of its credibility: since it was changed, it does not confirm the function after the change behaves the same way as before.

For an example, consider someone adding a call to `oven.preheat()` (optimization!) in your cookie baking example:

- If you mocked the oven object, it won't expect that call and fail the test, although the observable behavior of the method did not change (you still have a pan of cookies, hopefully).
- A stub might or might not fail, depending on whether you only added the methods to be tested or the whole interface with some dummy methods.
- A fake should not fail, since it should implement the method (according to the interface)

In my unit tests, I try to be as general as possible: If the implementation changes, but the visible behavior (from the perspective of the caller) is still the same, my tests should pass. Ideally, the only case I need to change an existing unit test should be a bug fix (of the test, not the function under test).

Comment: The problem is that as soon as you write `myDataStore.containsPerson('Joe')` you are assuming the existence of a functional test database.  Once you do that, you are writing an integration test and not a unit test.

Comment: I assume that I can rely on having a test data store (i don't care if that's a real or a mock one) and that everything works as set up (since I should have unit tests for those cases already). The only thing the test wants to test is that `savePeople()` actually adds those people to whatever data store you provide as long as that data store implements the expected interface.

An integration test would be, for example, checking that my database wrapper actually does the right database calls for a method call.

Comment: To clarify, if you are using a mock, all you can do is assert that a method on that mock was *called*, perhaps with some specific parameter.  You cannot assert on the state of the mock afterwards.  So if you want to make assertions on the state of the database after calling the method under test, as in `myDataStore.containsPerson('Joe')`, you have to use a functional db of some kind.  Once you take that step it's no longer a unit test.

Comment: it does not have to be a real database - just an object that implements the same interface as the real data store (read: it passes the relevant unit tests for the data store interface). I'd still consider this a mock. Let the mock store everything that gets added by any method for doing so in an array and check whether the test data (elements of `myPeople`) are in the array. IMHO a mock should still have the same observable behavior that is expected from a real object, otherwise you are testing for compliance with the mock interface, not the real interface.

Comment: "Let the mock store everything that gets added by any method for doing so in an array and check whether the test data (elements of myPeople) are in the array" -- that's still a "real" database, just an ad-hoc, in-memory one you have built.  "IMHO a mock should still have the same observable behavior that is expected from a real object" -- I suppose you can advocate for that, but that's not what "mock" means in the testing literature or in any of the popular libraries I've seen.  A mock simply verifies that expected methods are called with expected parameters.

Comment: Clarifying some of the language I used: With mock, I actually meant a stub or fake in the examples. Regarding the discussion about mocks displaying the behavior of the interface they replace: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) and [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665812/what-is-mocking) agree with me on that. Yes, you normally use mocks to verify expected method calls and parameters. No, for most unit test you don't actually have to go this far, especially if there isn't only one way to achieve a specific goal. They are really good for integration tests though.

Comment: Before calling `savePeople`, you probably should test that `myDataStore` does not  contain `Person('Joe')`. Otherwise, if `myDataStore` is a database that has already been used in other tests, there might be already a `Joe`. If `savePeople` somehow stops working, you wouldn't notice it.

Comment: You mention usage documentation, which is perhaps even more important because you know the code is correct and up to date (or the test would fail).

Comment: @EricDuminil Raises a very important point: `myDataStore` (whether it is a real database or a fake) _must_ be reset between every unit test. You can't use a real database that might also be used by other processes.

Comment: The problem is, it's probably a lot easier and faster to use actual database than re-implement a huge chunk of entire database functionality as part of "just an object that implements the same interface". We don't want to re-implement all 3rd party libs as complex and huge mocks.

Answer (score 15):

The primary value such a test provides is that it makes your implementation refactorable.

I used to do a lot of performance optimizations in my career and often found problems with the exact pattern you demonstrated: to save N entities into the database, perform N inserts.  It's usually more efficient to do a bulk insert using a single statement.

On the other hand, we don't want to prematurely optimize, either.  If you typically only save 1 - 3 people at a time, then writing an optimized batch may be overkill.

With a proper unit test, you can write it the way you implemented it above, and if you find you need to optimize it, you are free to do so with the safety net of an automated test to catch any errors.  Naturally, this varies based on the quality of the tests, so test liberally and test well.

The secondary advantage to unit testing this behavior is to serve as documentation for what its purpose is.  This trivial example may be obvious, but given the next point below, it could be very important.

The third advantage, which others have pointed out, is that you can test under-the-covers details which are very difficult to test with integration or acceptance tests.  For example, if there is a requirement that all users be saved atomically, then you can write a test case for that, which gives you a way to know it behaves as expected, and also serves as documentation for a requirement which may not be obvious to new developers.

I will add a thought which I got from a TDD instructor.  Don't test the method.  Test the behavior.  In other words, you don't test that `savePeople` works, you are testing that multiple users can be saved in a single call.

I found my ability to do quality unit testing and TDD improve when I stopped thinking about unit tests as verifying that a program works, but rather, they verify that a unit of code does *what I expect*.  Those are different.  They don't verify it works, but they verify it does what I think it does.  When I began thinking that way, my perspective changed.

Comment: The bulk insert refactoring example is a good one.  The possible unit test I suggested in the OP -- that a mock of dataStore has `savePerson` called on it for each person in the list -- would break with a bulk insert refactoring, however.  Which to me indicates that it's a poor unit test.  However, I don't see an alternative one that would pass both the bulk and one-save-per-person implementations, without using an actual test database and asserting against that, which seems wrong.  Could you provide a test that works for both implementations?

Comment: It also occurs to me now that if the parameter to `savePeople` were more strongly typed -- ie, in a statically typed language, an interface with `savePerson` rather than the entire `dataStore` object, which possibly has a `bulkInsertPeople` method as well -- then  that kind of refactoring becomes impossible without explicitly changing the method.

Comment: @Jonah Instead of testing `savePeople` by checking that `savePerson` is called for each person, you could *mock* `savePerson` to indicate that a specific person was saved and then assert that all the expected people were saved, thus covering the expected behavior independent of how it's implemented.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense to me. I can't imagine any test on `savePeople` that wouldn't break if you switched to a bulk insert.

Comment: @jpmc26 What about a test that tests that the people were saved...?

Comment: I agree, you should be able to test it.  The key is to test the *behavior*, not the implementation.  Meaning, don't test that a method is called in a loop, rather, test that all the objects wind up in the desired state.

Comment: @immibis I don't understand what that means. Presumably, the real store is backed by a database, so you'd have to mock or stub it for a unit test. So at that point, you would be testing that your mock or stub can store objects. That's utterly useless. The best you could do is assert that the `savePerson` method was called for each input, and if you replaced the loop with a bulk insert, you wouldn't be calling that method anymore. So your test would break. If you have something else in mind, I'm open to it, but I don't see it yet. (And not seeing it was my point.)

Comment: @jpmc26 You'd be testing that the method saved all the people in the mock data store. It likely wouldn't be a mock just for this test case, but a mock that works for all tests (and actually stores data, in a simpler way than the real data store).

Comment: @immibis I don't consider that a useful test. Using the fake data store doesn't give me any confidence it will work with the real thing. How do I know my fake works like the real thing? I would rather just let a suite of integration tests cover it. (I should probably clarify that I meant "any *unit* test" in my first comment here.)

Comment: @immibis I'm actually reconsidering my position. I've been skeptical about the value of unit tests because of problems like this, but maybe I'm underestimating the value even if you fake out an input. I *do* know that input/output testing tends to be *much* more useful than mock heavy tests, but maybe a refusal to replace an input with a fake is actually part of the problem here.

Comment: @jpmc26 Exactly!  Mocking is a great example because developers often figure, if you mock something, you aren't testing the real thing, so what's the point?  But if you stop thinking about testing that the code works and think about testing that it does what you expect, suddenly mocking makes some sense.

Answer (score 6):

Should `bakeCookies()` be tested? Yes.

> How should a function like this be unit tested, assuming you think it should? It's hard for me to imagine any kind of unit test that doesn't simply mock dough, pan, and oven, and then assert that methods are called on them.

Not really. Look closely at WHAT the function is supposed to do - it is supposed to set the `oven` object to a specific state. Looking at the code it appears that the states of the `pan` and `dough` objects does not really matter much. So you should pass an `oven` object (or mock it) and assert that it is in a particular state at the end of the function call.

In other words, **you should assert that `bakeCookies()` baked the cookies**.

For very short functions, unit tests may appear to be little more than tautology. But don't forget, your program is going to last a lot longer than the time you are employed writing it. That function may or may not change in the future.

Unit tests serves two functions:

1. It tests that everything works. This is the least useful function unit tests serves and it appears that you seem to only consider this functionality when asking the question.
2. It checks to see that future modifications of the program does not break functionality that was previously implemented. This is the most useful function of unit tests and it prevents introduction of bugs into large programs. It is useful in normal coding when adding features to the program but it is more useful in refactoring and optimisations where the core algorithms implementing the program are dramatically changed without changing any observable behaviour of the program.

Do not test the code inside the function. Instead test that the function does what it says it does. When you look at unit tests this way (testing functions, not code) then you will realise that you never test language constructs or even application logic. You are testing an API.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply.  Would you mind looking at my 2nd update and giving your thoughts about how to unit test the function in that example?

Comment: I find that this can be effective when you can either use a real oven or a fake oven, but is significantly less effective with a mock oven. Mocks (by the Meszaros defintions) don't have any state, other than a record of the methods that have been called on them. My experience is that when functions like `bakeCookies` are tested in this way, they tend to break during refactors that would not impact the observable behaviour of the application.

Comment: @James_pic, exactly.  And yes, that is the mock definition I am using.  So given your comment, what do you do in a case like this?  Forgo the test?  Write the brittle, implementation-repeating test anyway?  Something else?

Comment: @Jonah I'll generally either look at testing that component with integration tests (I've found the warnings about it being harder to debug to be overblown, possibly due to the quality of modern tooling), or go to the trouble of creating a semi-convincing fake.

Answer (score 3):

> Should savePeople() be unit tested, or would such tests amount to testing the built-in forEach language construct?

Yes. But you *could* do it in a way that would just retest the construct.

The thing to note here is how does this function behave when a `savePerson` fails half way through? How is it supposed to work?

*That* is the sort of subtle behavior that the function provides that you should enforce with unit tests.

Comment: Yes, I agree that subtle error conditions *should* be tested, but imo that is not an interesting question -- the answer is clear.  Hence the reason I specifically stated that, for purposes of my question, `savePeople` should not be responsible for error handling.   To clarify again, *assuming* that `savePeople` is responsible *only* for iterating through the list and delegating the saving of each item to another method, should it still be tested?

Comment: @Jonah: If you're going to insist on confining your unit test solely to the `foreach` construct, and not any conditions, side effects or behaviors outside of it, then you're right; the new unit test is really not all that interesting.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Please re-read the last paragraph of my OP, as your last comment is misrepresenting my position.  I even gave the logical unit test and mocks that, imo, could reasonably be argued for.  I am trying to get feedback about the appropriateness of such tests, specifically.  I know it's fun to poke holes in all the flaws of a simplified example, but those are things I am well aware of and aren't helpful in giving me the insight I'm looking for.

Comment: @jonah - should it iterate through and save as many as possible or stop on error? The single save _can't_ decide that, since it can't know how it's being used.

Comment: @Jonah: The title of the question states specifically that you're interested primarily in discussing the `foreach` language construct, and you're deflecting comments that have nothing to do with that.

Comment: @Telastyn, This is a magical database that cannot possibly error.  However, it is possible that other developers on this project may decide to edit `savePeople` in some way.  Do you still unit test it?  If so, how?

Comment: @jonah - magical databases don't exist. Since you are not a unicorn, you test the unhappy paths.

Comment: how about magical posters whose superpower is to avoid answering the question being asked under guise of virtuous preaching ?  do those exist?

Comment: @jonah - welcome to the site. One of the key components of our Q&A format is that we're not here to help _you_. Your question helps you of course, but it also helps many other people who come to the site looking for answers to their questions. I answered the question you asked. It's not my fault if you don't like the answer or would rather shift the goalposts. And frankly, it looks like the other answers say the same basic thing, albeit more eloquently.

Comment: @Telastyn, I'm trying to gain insight about unit testing.  My initial question was not clear enough, so I'm adding clarifications to steer the conversation toward my *real* question.  You are choosing to interpret that as me somehow cheating you in the game of "being right."  I have spent hundreds of hours answering questions on code review and SO.  My purpose is always to help the people I'm answering.  If yours isn't, that's your choice.  You don't have to answer my questions.

Comment: The attitude adjustment department is located [here](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3):

The key here is your perspective on a particular function as trivial. Most of programming is trivial: assign a value, do some math, make a decision: if this then that, continue a loop until... In isolation, all trivial. You just got through the first 5 chapters of any book teaching a programming language.

The fact that writing a test is so easy should be a sign that your design is not that bad. Would you prefer a design that is not easy to test?

"That will never change." is how most failed projects start out. A unit test only determines if the unit works as expected under a certain set of circumstances. Get it to pass and then you can forget about its implementation details and just use it. Use that brain space for the next task.

Knowing things work as expected is very important and not trivial in large projects and especially large teams. If there's one thing programmers have in common, is the fact we've all had to deal with someone else's terrible code. The least we can do is have some tests. When in doubt, write a test and move on.

Comment: Thanks for you feedback.  Good points.  The question I really want answered (I just added yet another update to clarify) is the appropriate way to test functions that do nothing more than call a sequence of other services through delegation.  In such cases, it seems the unit tests appropriate to "document the contract" are just a restatement of the function implementation, asserting that methods are called on various mocks.  Yet the test being identical to the implementation in those cases feels wrong....

Answer (score 2):

I think your question boils down to:

How do I unit test a void function without it being an integration test?

If we change your cookie baking function to return cookies for example it becomes immediately obvious what the test should be.

If we have to call pan.GetCookies after calling the function though we can question whether its 'really an integration test' or 'but arent we just testing the pan object?'

I think you are correct in that having unit tests with everything mocked and just checking functions x y and z were called lack value.

But! I would argue that in these case you should refactor your void functions to return a testable result OR use real objects and make an integration test

--- Update for the createNewUser example

- a new user record needs to be created in the database
- a welcome email needs to be sent
- the user's IP address needs to be recorded for fraud purposes.

OK so this time the result of the function is not easily returned. We want to change the state of the parameters.

This is where I get slightly controversial. 
**I create concrete mock implementations for the stateful parameters**

please, dear readers, try and control your rage!

so...

```
var validatedUserData = new UserData(); //we can use the real object for this
var emailService = new MockEmailService(); //a simple mock which saves sentEmails to a List<string>
var dataStore = new MockDataStore(); //a simple mock which saves ips to a List<string>

//run the test
target.createNewUser(validatedUserData, emailService, dataStore);

//check the results
Assert.AreEqual(1, emailService.EmailsSent.Count());
Assert.AreEqual(1, dataStore.IpsRecorded.Count());
Assert.AreEqual(1, dataStore.UsersSaved.Count());
```

This separates the implementation detail of the method under test from the desired behavior. An alternate implementation :

```
function createNewUser(validatedUserData, emailService, dataStore) {
  userId = dataStore.bulkInsedrtUserRecords(new [] {validateduserData});
  emailService.addEmailToQueue(validatedUserData);
  emailService.ProcessQueue();
  dataStore.recordIpAddress(userId, validatedUserData.ip);
}
```

Will still pass the unit test. Plus you have the advantage of being able to reuse the mock objects across tests and also inject them into your application for UI or Integration Tests.

Comment: it's not an integration test simply because you mention the names of 2 concrete classes ... integration tests are about testing integrations with external systems, like disk IO, the DB, external web services and so on.calling pan.getCookies() is in-memory, fast, checks for the thing we're interested in etc. I agree that having the method return the cookies directly feels like a better design though.

Comment: Wait. For all we know pan.getcookies sends an email to a cook asking them to take the cookies out of the oven when they get a chance

Comment: I guess it's theoretically possible, but it'd be a pretty misleading name. who ever heard of oven equipment that sent emails? but I see you point, it depends. I assume these collaborating classes are leaf objects or just plain in-memory things, but if they do sneaky stuff, then caution is needed. I think email sending definitely should be done at a higher level than this though. this seems like the down and dirty business logic in the entities.

Comment: It was a rhetorical question, but:

"who ever heard of oven equipment that sent emails?"

http://venturebeat.com/2016/03/08/tovala-launches-kickstarter-campaign-to-accept-pre-orders-for-its-connected-oven/

Comment: Hi Ewan, I think this answer is coming closest so far to what I'm really asking.  I think your point about `bakeCookies` returning the baked cookies is spot on, and I had some thought after posting it.  So I think it's yet again not a great example.  I added one more update that hopefully provides a more realistic example of what's motivating my question.  I'd appreciate your input.

Comment: not sure i understand the exception bit. you want to test the exceptions are thrown?

Comment: Thanks for the update!  The exception bit was meant "don't worry about exceptions," which your answer doesn't.  Your answer is definitely in the spirit of what I'm looking for.  That said, I have reservations.  If your mocks are implementing the real, non-trivial functionality of those objects, don't they become complex enough to start warranting tests of their own? And with lines like `emailService.EmailsSent.Count()`, aren't we now letting our tests dictate the API of its collaborators?  What if we otherwise don't need `EmailsSent`?

Comment: The concrete class implements the Interface, but the test references the concrete class. So it can have the extra methods

Comment: These mock implementations are usualy trivial but if you are testing the real version of the interface, you can run those same tests against the mock

Comment: "The concrete class implements the Interface, but the test references the concrete class. So it can have the extra methods" -- do you mean `EmailsSent` would exist only on the mock?  Aren't you now testing your mock itself (which isn't a pure mock anymore)?  All you can count on is that the `EmailService` has certain methods.  Your choices are then to assert that those methods are called (correct way to use mocks, but trivially repeating implementation details) or to use real objects, at which point you're writing an integration test, even if the "real" object is a simple thing you've built.

Comment: Hence my origional point "how do i unit test a void function without it being an integration test" or rather 'being called an intergration test

Comment: @Ewan, yes, you are right, it does boil down to that, i think.  so i guess the answer is, you can't?  so what do you do?  in the bake cookies example, your answer was: change the method to return something.  but with methods like the create user example, i don't an obvious way to rewrite it.  But maybe this is telling us that such methods are a code smell?

Comment: its best to write idempotent methods where possible, but in real life you have state. Where state affects the result of the function, or the function should affect state you have to include that state in your mock. Doing that with Moq style frameworks is possible but leads to very complex test setups

Comment: I still disagree with your belief that the mocks should have state. Creating such a mocks is in my opinion even worse than creating the trivial tests that retest implementation by checking that methods are called on a mock.  it's a complete illusion that these functional mocks in which you are asserting on state at the end are allowing you to test behavior rather than implementation.  other than that we're on the same page tho...

Comment: What do you think happens when you call Assert(Moq.MethodHasBeenCalled)? its stateful, just hard to setup. But you dont complain that you are only testing the moq framework

Comment: two important differences: Moq is well tested itself, and its scope is smaller, you aren't trying to recreate a db.  I don't think your instinct is wrong, but I think the answer you're leaning towards and that seems more and more right to me is that you really need to do an integration test here.  once you decide that I think you should use A copy of your actual database the tests populate with test data.  so you have a local copy of postgres eg that you use here and assert against

Comment: Moq is a complex framework. When you consider the setup required to test if one two method have been fired vs a simple List + link mock...

Comment: In the end literally the only useful answer gets the least upvotes and sits on the end of the list. I keep feeling everything about TDD is constantly so out of reality.

Comment: I would update this answer as these days you can use Moq to add an inline function to methods which will update a local list variable. so you "writing a concrete class" can be done inline in the test

Answer (score 2):

> Should savePeople() be unit tested, or would such tests amount to testing the built-in forEach language construct?

This has already been answered by @BryanOakley, but I have some extra arguments (I guess):

First a unit test is for testing the fulfillment of a contract, not the implementation of an API; the test should set preconditions then call, then check for effects, side effects, any invariants and post conditions. When you decide what to test, **the implementation of the API doesn't (and shouldn't) matter**.

Second, your test will be there to check the invariants *when the function changes*. The fact it doesn't change *now* doesn't mean you shouldn't have the test.

Third, there is value in having implemented a trivial test, both in a TDD approach (which mandates it) and outside of it.

When writing C++, for my classes, I tend to write a trivial test that instantiates an object and checks invariants (assignable, regular, etc). I found it surprising how many times this test is broken during development (by - for example - adding a non-movable member in a class, by mistake).

Answer (score 0):

You should also test `bakeCookies` - what would/should e..g `bakeCookies(egg, pan, oven)` yield? Fried egg or an exception? On their own, neither `pan` nor `oven` will care about the actual ingredients, since none of them are supposed to, but `bakeCookies` should usually yield cookies. More generally it can depend on how `dough` is obtained and whether there *is* any chance of it becoming mere `egg` or e.g. `water` instead.